# Imprimir todos los datos de un CSV en Java

Tags: java, csv

estoy intentado imprimir los datos de un csv en java. He intentado de esta manera.

```
String archCSV = "D:\\ISO-Codes.csv";
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(archCSV));
String[] fila = null;
while((fila = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
    System.out.println(fila[0]
              + " | " + fila[1]
              + " |  " + fila[2]);
}

csvReader.close();
```

Pero en este ejemplo debo conocer la cantidad de columnas y como son diferentes mis archivos csv que tengo que imprimir. Como especifico n cantidad de columnas.

Comment: por favor agrega los imports, pues hay varias clases que se llaman `CSVReader` en distintas librerías

Comment: Estoy utilizando import com.opencsv.CSVReader;

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar este algoritmo para leer primero el archivo csv y extraer toda la data

```
public Stream<String> leerAchivoExterno(String rutaArchivo) {
    Stream<String> lineas = null;

    try {
        lineas = Files.lines(Paths.get(rutaArchivo), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("error "+ex);
    }

    return lineas;
}
```

Y posteriormente, revisa el separador que puede ser una coma, o comunmente un punto coma para establecer las columnas e ir ordenando la data completamente.

```
List<String> lineas = pm.leerAchivoExterno("").collect(Collectors.toList());
   lineas.forEach(fila -> {
       System.out.println("data: "+fila.split(";").toString());
   });
```