# Imprimir todos los datos de un archivo CSV en Java

Tags: java, csv

Intento imprimir en pantalla todos los datos de un archivo csv. Ya que son diferentes archivos csv, no conozco la cantidad de columnas.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < listaRutasArchivos.getSize(); i++) {
        String ruta = listaRutasArchivos.getElementAt(i);

        try {
            file = new File(ruta);
            fileReader = new FileReader(ruta);
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(fileReader, ',');
            String[] fila = null;
            int numCol=0;
            while ((fila = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                numCol=fila.length;
                System.out.println(fila.toString());
            }
            System.out.println("CANTIDAD "+numCol);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(app.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Si pudieran aconsejarme de que manera puedo realizarlo, anteriormente leí para leer un archivo podría usar el siguiente código, pero eso es conociendo la cantidad de columnas. Aclaro que la respuesta dada anteriormente, no funciono.

```
  while((fila = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
        System.out.println(fila[0]
          + " | " + fila[1]
          + " |  " + fila[2]);
  }
```

Comment: Esta pregunta ya tiene una respuesta en [Imprimir todos los datos de un csv en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/235809/imprimir-todos-los-datos-de-un-csv-en-java)

Comment: Si la pregunta que ya hiciste, respecto de este mismo tema no resolvio ese problema. porque no la editas y aclaras mejor el problema?